# Spree Commerce: any themes?

Tags: themes, spree

I searched whole morning, and find out that there aren't any themes either to purchase or download for Spree. It seems that I have to build custom store front myself.

Spree seems to be very limited in this aspect when compared to OpenCart and PrestaShops.

Am I right?

Comment: I just added another theme to the list below, the Spree Fancy theme https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy

Answer (score 16):

There are a few themes publicly available:

- https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy
- http://spreecommerce.com/extensions/254-spree_multi_theme
- https://github.com/spree/spree_rdr_theme
- https://github.com/sammyd/spree_tuatun_theme
- https://github.com/spree/spree_blue_theme

As well as other available here: https://github.com/search?langOverride=&q=spree+theme&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories

Comment: spree_tuatun_theme does not even work